# Regex for no duplicate characters from a limited character pool

Tags: regex

Is there a way to write a regex to match a string that only contains certain characters, and never repeats those characters? I already wrote some code using a set to implement this, but would like to know if there's a regex way to do it.

So for example, if I only wanted a string that contains [A,B,C], and I want to match to a string that never duplicates any of those characters, eg A, B, C, AB, AC, B, BC, ABC, and so on, but never matches AA, BB, CC, etc

Thanks!

Comment: regex isn't very good for this requirement.  Sure, if you have a limited amount of characters, you could brute-force it by having a regex that explicitly matches every case that you want, but otherwise, your non-regex solution is probably preferable

Comment: By "repeat", I assume you don't restrict yourself to direct repeats? `ABA` should not match, or should it?

Comment: To prevent a direct repeat, its just this `^(?:([ABC])(?!\1))+$` which is entirely different than any repeat.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's easy to do with a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABC]+$
```

matches exactly as you described.

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/fN3eR1/2).

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of the string
(?!    # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 .*    # Any number of characters (including zero)
 (.)   # followed by one character (remember this one in group 1)
 .*    # that's followed by any number of characters
 \1    # and the same character as before
)      # End of lookahead
[ABC]+ # Match one or more characters from this list
$      # until the end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping the regex101 content up

Comment: Thank you so much for the regex explanation, too 

Answer (score 2):

[`back referencing`](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.back-references.php) can be used. Here comes an example in PHP, which is compatible to Perl regular expressions:

```
$string = "A, B, C, AB, AC, B, BC, AABC";

if(preg_match('/([ABC])\1/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1] . " has been repeated\n";
} else {
    echo "OK\n";
}
```

In the above pattern `([ABC])` is capturing group which can store one out of the characters `A`, `B` or `C`. `\1` references this first capturing group, this makes the pattern matching if one those characters repeats.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this question

[Visual C++ Regex: Matching no repeating letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176992/visual-c-regex-matching-no-repeating-letter)

which was marked an exact duplicate of this question.

No repeating of any letter ?
Does that mean consecutive letters, or is `abaca` ok ?

if not, the regex would be yours modified to this :

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*([a-z]).*\1).{4,20}$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?= .* [a-z] )
 (?!
      .* 
      ( [a-z] )                     # (1)
      .* \1 
 )
 .{4,20} 
 $
```