# Regex operator and grep -E fail

Tags: regex, bash

I found the perfect regex for my needs here: [Regex for no duplicate characters from a limited character pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470820/regex-for-no-duplicate-characters-from-a-limited-character-pool) [Live demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/fN3eR1/2)

But when I test it with bash regex operator it always fails:

```
if [[ 'ABC' =~ ^(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABC]+$ ]]; then
        echo "success"
else
        echo "fail"
fi
```

I also tried it with grep:

```
echo "ABC" | grep -E "^(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABC]+$"
```

But I got *"grep: Invalid back reference"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `-P` of grep :

```
echo "ABC" | grep -P '^(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABC]+$'
```

Comment: However, it will only work with GNU grep.

Answer (score 2):

There is no lookaround support in POSIX ERE, so you need to introduce a second condition:

```sh
s='ABCC'
rx1='^[ABC]+$'
rx2='(.).*\1'
if [[ "$s" =~ $rx1 && ! "$s" =~ $rx2 ]]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

See the [Bash online demo](https://ideone.com/S2TGVN).

*Details*:

- `"$s" =~ ^[ABC]+$` - checks that the whole `s` string consists of one or more `A`, `B` or `C` chars
- `&& ! "$s" =~ (.).*\1` - and another condition requires the `s` string to have no repeating character.

Comment: ABCC gives "success" instead of failing :(

Comment: @Giulio Just let's use best practices and define the regex patterns with single quoted strings assigned to variables. Then the shell won't fool us with escaping. This approach works as expected and will work in Bash without relying on whether you have a GNU grep or not.